# I've waited 4 days for my MX records to populate to activate gmail but it still says I need to add the new google MX records and delete my old

Tags: gmail, mx

My domain host has reflected the proper google MX records for 4 days now:

5  @ ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5  @ ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 @ ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 @ ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
1  @ ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

However, when I return to google's activate gmail tool for it to check my mx records and confirm that the right email settings are added, it keeps saying I'm missing all 5 google records and that I need to delete "30 @ mail.mydomain.com" which is already long gone.

None of google's instructions or helps seem to address my situation. I've also deleted old A Records that included any references to mail or pointing to old servers. I'm not sure what else to do and its very frustrating because our business has had the hardest time using work arounds on our existing platform to receive mail. Please help, thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

> it keeps saying I'm missing all 5 google records and that I need to delete "30 @ mail.mydomain.com" which is already long gone.

DNS records are served up with information about caching (following shows an interaction with DNS using nslookup):

```
> set type=SOA
> google.com
;; communications error to 172.27.64.1#53: timed out
Server:         172.27.64.1
Address:        172.27.64.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
google.com
        origin = ns1.google.com
        mail addr = dns-admin.google.com
        serial = 538438804
        refresh = 900
        retry = 900
        expire = 1800
        minimum = 60
```

(the refresh, retry, expire and minumum values are in seconds)

While its now impossible to tell what the cache values were at the time Google read them AND we can't know when Google retrieved the data / started the countdown, it is unlikely that your provider has changed the SOA (cache) data - check what the current settings are now and wait that long before worrying about this.

Comment: Thx symcbean, but I don't think I understand what you're saying. So are you saying I should delete the records fully, wait for that to update and replace the old cache, then re-add the records and try again? If not, what are you suggesting I do?

Comment: Check the records are as intended in whatever tool you use to manage the DNS records. Check what the current expiry time is. Wait that long. The re-test.

Comment: OK, I see. Yes, the DNS MX records are correct, and I have re-tested a few times a day for a week, so that is not fixing it. I will try to delete the records, wait an hour, re-add them, wait again, then retest. Here's praying for great news!

Comment: No, its still not working =(

Answer (score 1):

SO! It turns out that I had to contact my nameserver company and THEY had to ALSO update their mx records to match the ones I added in my DNS settings.

Comment: when you are able, can you accept this answer as correct so it helps others in the future.